# Generically implementing a trait for all concrete types implementing another trait

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new to rust, so this might be a stupid question with an obvious answer, but I don't know the answer yet. I've just read the book and then decided to implement some algorithms I'm familiar with, to get a feeling for the language. That, however, took me down a dark path to a side project that went a little deeper into the language than I had planned for...

Anyway, I'm now playing around with some code for working with indices and offsets in some algorithms in a type-safe way. I have indices into different arrays and strings and want to prevent using an index from one array to be used into another and things like that. So, I have defined new types for different kinds of indices, those with different domains, and for offsets between them. I don't allow comparisons between domains, I can subtract indices to get an offset and I can add and subtract indices and offsets and stuff like that. Further, I can define which types of objects indices can subscript, so an index into a string can only index a string and not, say, a suffix array, where another type is necessary.

This mostly works. I have a bunch of macros for defining what objects are allowed to do. For example, with this

```rust
def_offset!(Offset);
def_idx!(
    Idx
    with offset Offset
    with sub [
        Vec<T>[Idx] => T,
        [T][Idx] => T
    ]
);
```

I define a generic `Offset` that you can do arithmics on but nothing else, and then an index type `Idx` that can do arithmics with `Offset` and index vectors and slices. The arithmetic for indices looks like this right now, but I'm not done experimenting with it

```rust
macro_rules! def_idx_ops {
    ($idx:ident with offset $offset:ident) => {
        // You can add an index and an offset
        def_op!($idx + $offset => $idx);
        def_op!($offset + $idx => $idx);
        def_op!($idx += $offset);

        // You can subtract an index and an offset
        def_op!($idx - $offset => $idx);
        def_op!($idx -= $offset);

        // You can subtract two indices, but you can't add
        // them (adding indices do not usually make sense)
        def_op!($idx - $idx => $offset);

        // You can add scalars to indices.
        def_op!($idx + usize => $idx);
        def_op!(usize + $idx => $idx);
        def_op!($idx += usize);

        // You can subtract scalars from indices.
        def_op!($idx - usize => $idx);
        def_op!(usize - $idx => $idx);
        def_op!($idx -= usize);
    };
}
```

where the `def_op!` macro implements the appropriate trait for the types involved in the operator.

There is more code generation going on here than I like, but I couldn't figure out how to write generic code any other way. But maybe I will after this question.

See, now I got to implementing ranges over these types. They come out of the box if you just want a range

```
let r = Idx(0)..Idx(10)
```

but you can't iterate over them. For that, you need to implement some traits. With the code below, it works for the type `Idx`:

```rust
// Trait for implementing iteration through i..j ranges for Idx.
// NB: This requires nightly; the iter::Step trait is unstable.
impl std::iter::Step for Idx {
    fn steps_between(start: &Self, end: &Self) -> Option<usize> {
        match (start.0, end.0) {
            (i, j) if i > j => None,
            (i, j) => Some(j - i),
        }
    }
    fn forward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        Some(start + count) // Ignoring overflow here...
    }
    fn backward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        match start.0 {
            i if i < count => None,
            _ => Some(start - count),
        }
    }
}
```

But it only works for the concrete type `Idx`. If I try to make a generic implementation, I run into all kinds of trouble.

This is my current attempt, but it works as little as the others I have made:

```rust
trait RangeIndex<T>: NumWrapper<T> + std::ops::Add<T> + std::ops::Sub<T>
where
    T: num::traits::NumCast,
{
}

impl<Idx> std::iter::Step for Idx
where
    Idx: RangeIndex<usize>,
{
    fn steps_between(start: &Self, end: &Self) -> Option<usize> {
        match (start.wrapped(), end.wrapped()) {
            (i, j) if i > j => None,
            (i, j) => Some(j - i),
        }
    }
    fn forward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        Some(start + count) // Ignoring overflow here...
    }
    fn backward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        match start.wrapped() {
            i if i < count => None,
            _ => Some(start - count),
        }
    }
}
```

The `RangeIndex<T>` trait puts the constraints I need on the index type, and `NumWrapper` is a trait for the numbers I'm wrapping in indices and offsets.

```rust
pub trait Wrapper<Wrapped> {
    fn wrapped(&self) -> Wrapped;
}

pub trait NumWrapper<Wrapped>:
    Wrapper<Wrapped> + std::cmp::PartialEq + std::cmp::PartialOrd
where
    Wrapped: num::traits::NumCast,
{
    fn cast_to_wrapped<T: num::traits::NumCast>(val: T) -> Wrapped {
        num::cast(val).unwrap()
    }
}
```

(There is a little more to the wrapped objects, but this is the only relevant part for treating them as numbers).

This generic code does not work. The compiler suggests that I make the trait `dyn` but I assure you that I do not want to do that. I don't want any dynamic dispatch or polymorphism at all. I have concrete types; I want implementations for those. Nothing more and nothing less.

It is a small matter to just generate the code with macros, like I have with the operators. But I am reinventing generic code now, and that is deeply unsatisfying. I feel the same way about generating the operators instead of having code for traits and then just implementing the appropriate trait for each type.

Is it impossible to say "for any type that implements this particular trait, give me a concrete implementation of this trait like this"? It is really all I want. For any `Idx` that implements these traits, give me this `std::iter::Step`.

And if I can get that, I would love to do the same with the operators

```rust
impl<LHS, RHS, RES> std::ops::Add<RHS> for LHS {
    where //"some constraint involving both LHS and RHS and RES"
          Constraint<LHS,RHS,RES> // yeah, might not be able to do this
    type Output = RES;
    fn add(self, rhs: $rhs) -> Self::Output {
        RES(RES::cast_to_wrapped(self.wrapped()) + 
            RES::cast_to_wrapped(rhs.wrapped()))
    }
}
```

One can dream, at least.

Anyway, I don't mind generating the operators, but I see it as a problem if I have to give up on generic code that works with these types. If I can't even run through a range, then this project is going to die pretty soon. Using macros for every generic function just isn't an attractive idea. (Well, I can still write generic functions, I just cannot implement traits, so it is not all that bad, but it still is pretty bad).

Really, what I want to tell Rust is that "for all types that implement the following traits", "give me an instance of this generic code". Exactly what I can get with macros, I suppose, but using generics that were made for this purpose instead.

Surely there must be some well know trick to generically implementing a trait without resorting to `dyn`?

**UPDATE**

I've put a related exampled on playground. The full example where I need the ranges is a bit too long, but I think the smaller example hits the same issue. There, I have a trait for adding wrapped numbers

```rust
// Local trait for adding ... a substitute for the range code I need
trait MyAdd<Rhs> {
    type Res;
    fn my_add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Res;
}
```

I can implement `std::ops::Add` just from this interface, but no matter how I try, I cannot do it without explicitly implementing that trait for each type I define. There are a couple of examples of my attempts, but needless to say, they do not work.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af5f9087a2736904e0c09f3f1674826f)

Comment: I suggest including the compiler's error messages, and ideally a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) link to the code. I think the issue is you're running up against Rust's coherence/orphan rules.

Comment: It is likely the orphan rule; I have hit it before. There, I managed to get around it by wrapping types, but this time I want to go in the other direction. I made a smaller example and put it on playground https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af5f9087a2736904e0c09f3f1674826f

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the playground example, it's not possible to do what you want. This type of impl can't work:

```rust
impl<X, RHS> std::ops::Add<RHS> for X
where
    X: MyAdd<RHS>,
{
    type Output = X::Res;
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output {
        self.my_add(rhs)
    }
}
```

It is a blanket impl, as we are implementing a trait for a bare type parameter `X`. But only the crate that defines the trait being impl'd (in this case `std::ops::Add`) is allowed to write a blanket impl for that trait.

Comment: That makes sense. Although so don’t want to implement this for every type, just those that implement the given trait, so am providing implementations beyond my crate. But is there no possible way to get the same effect using generics? It is trivial to do with macros, so it seems a bit silly that I can’t do it with generics.

Answer (score 2):

I fought it a bit more, and I think I might have a solution. Since I can't implement a trait for general types, but only types in my own crate, that is what I have to do. I didn't want to, because I wanted to use the types to define different operators, but I figured that there would be a way around that.

Here is what I have right now. I define a type to contain information about the wrapped objects I will hold. Then I am going to wrap objects, and use instances of this type as tags, to give my wrappers different underlying types, and that way define operators.

```rust
// Any of the wrapped types should have this.
pub trait TypeInfo: Copy {
    type WrappedType: Copy + num::PrimInt;
}
```

This just tells me what the underlying type is, when I get to that; that turns out to be important.

Then I define a trait for wrapper objects. They have TypeInfo to make macros and meta-programming easier, but they are not the same as the TypeInfo objects. They implement it, and they contain one.

```rust
// A few places, this is useful for meta-programming. Mostly because I can't
// get the From<> trait to work half the time...
pub trait WrapInfo: TypeInfo {
    fn wrapped(&self) -> Self::WrappedType;
    fn wrapped_as<T: num::PrimInt + Copy>(&self) -> T {
        num::cast::<Self::WrappedType, T>(self.wrapped()).unwrap()
    }
}
```

I also implement this trait for primitive integers, because otherwise I have to do a lot of case-analysis when I write macros later. If all the objects I implement operators on behave the same, then I don't need to worry about that.

```rust
// Type info for primitive types; we will wrap those for specific
// type-safe types. Having the traits for all numbers makes meta-programming
// a lot easier. Numerical types just wrap themselves.
impl<T> TypeInfo for T
where
    T: Copy + num::PrimInt,
{
    type WrappedType = T;
}
impl<T> WrapInfo for T
where
    T: Copy + num::PrimInt,
{
    fn wrapped(&self) -> Self::WrappedType {
        *self
    }
}
```

My wrapper looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Wrapper<_Tag>(pub _Tag::WrappedType)
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo;

impl<_Tag> TypeInfo for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
{
    type WrappedType = _Tag::WrappedType;
}
impl<_Tag> WrapInfo for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
{
    fn wrapped(&self) -> _Tag::WrappedType {
        self.0
    }
}
```

It is parameterised with a `_Tag` of type `TypeInfo`, but it doesn't hold one of those types. It holds a value of `_Tag::WrappedType`. That way, I don't have to dereference through layers of nesting but always have the type as `wrapped.0`, but I still get the type safety I am going for. When I have two `Wrapper<_Tag>` objects with different `_Tag`, they are different types.

I add some other useful traits, and I am sure that there are more worth adding...

```rust
impl<_Tag> std::fmt::Display for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
    _Tag::WrappedType: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

// Get an ordering on it
impl<_Tag> std::cmp::PartialEq for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Wrapper<_Tag>) -> bool {
        self.0 == other.0
    }
}
impl<_Tag> std::cmp::PartialOrd for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
{
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Wrapper<_Tag>) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        self.0.partial_cmp(&other.0)
    }
}

impl<T, _Tag> From<T> for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    T: num::PrimInt,
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
{
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Wrapper::<_Tag>(num::cast::<T, _Tag::WrappedType>(t).unwrap())
    }
}
```

Now, for the range iterator, I can just implement it on `Wrapper`:

```rust
impl<_Tag> std::iter::Step for Wrapper<_Tag>
where
    _Tag: TypeInfo,
{
    fn steps_between(start: &Self, end: &Self) -> Option<usize> {
        match (start.wrapped(), end.wrapped()) {
            (i, j) if i > j => None,
            (i, j) => num::cast(j - i),
        }
    }
    fn forward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        let count = num::cast::<usize, _Tag::WrappedType>(count)?;
        Some(Wrapper::<_Tag>(start.wrapped() + count))
    }
    fn backward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        let count = num::cast::<usize, _Tag::WrappedType>(count)?;
        Some(Wrapper::<_Tag>(start.wrapped() - count))
    }
}
```

Rust doesn't complain about this, since `Wrapper` is a type from this crate. It is still generic, though, because the `_Tag` can vary.

I tried to do something similar with operators, but I gave up. My problem was that I parameterise the result type in a way that I couldn't easily get into the types when you define the appropriate traits. I suspect, though, that you can get there with another level of re-direction and have a trait like `Op<Lhs,Rhs,Res>` that implements the various traits, and then implement `Op<Wrapper<_lhsTag>,Wrapper<_rhsTag>, Wrapper<_resTag>>` or something, but here I am not sure how to get primitive types into it without a lot of case analysis again.

For now, I have macros, and they suit me fine. Here is addition and subtraction:

```rust
macro_rules! def_op {
    ($lhs:ident + $rhs:ident => $res:ident) => {
        impl std::ops::Add<$rhs> for $lhs {
            type Output = $res;
            fn add(self, rhs: $rhs) -> Self::Output {
                let lhs: <$res as TypeInfo>::WrappedType = self.wrapped_as();
                let rhs: <$res as TypeInfo>::WrappedType = rhs.wrapped_as();
                (lhs + rhs).into()
            }
        }
    };

    ($lhs:ident - $rhs:ident => $res:ident) => {
        impl std::ops::Sub<$rhs> for $lhs {
            type Output = $res;
            fn sub(self, rhs: $rhs) -> Self::Output {
                let lhs: <$res as TypeInfo>::WrappedType = self.wrapped_as();
                let rhs: <$res as TypeInfo>::WrappedType = rhs.wrapped_as();
                (lhs - rhs).into()
            }
        }
    };
}
```

With another macro I can automate the type declarations, and then add some operators. (I will figure out a way to automate the operator selection a little more later).

```rust
// This bit requires the paste crate
use paste::paste;
macro_rules! def_wrapped {
    ($name:ident[$wrapped:ty]) => {
        paste! {
            #[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
            pub struct [<_ $name tag>]();
            impl TypeInfo for [<_ $name tag>] {
                type WrappedType = $wrapped;
            }
            pub type $name = Wrapper<[<_ $name tag>]>;
        }
    };
}

def_wrapped!(I[usize]); // Index with usize
def_wrapped!(O[isize]); // Offset with isize

// Some appropriate operators
def_op!(I + O => I);
def_op!(I - O => I);
def_op!(I - I => O);
def_op!(I + usize => I);
```

And now, it seems this design is close to what I had before in functionality, but with fewer macros and more generics.

```rust
fn main() {
    let i: I = I::from(0);
    let j: I = 10.into();
    let k: O = j - i;
    println!("{} {} {}", i, j, i + k);
    println!("arithmetic with index and offset: {}", i + k);
    println!("arithmetic with index and usize: {}", i + 12);
    println!("{}", i + k);
    for i in I::from(0)..I::from(10) {
        println!("i = {}", i);
    }
    for k in O::from(-10)..O::from(10) {
        println!("k = {}", k);
    }
}
```

I fully expect to run into something that throws it into disarray next time I look at it, but at least there is something up and running for now.