# Specialising Range or overloading ".."

Tags: rust

I have a little library where I can define integer types. These are intended for type-safe indexing into arrays and strings in the kind of algorithms I often write. For example, I can use it to define an offset type, `Offset` and an index type, `Idx` such that you can get an `Offset` by subtracting two `Idx`, you can get `Idx` by adding or subtracting `Offset`, but you cannot for example multiple or add `Idx`.

```rust
let (i,j): (Idx,Idx) = ...;
let offset: Offset = j - i; // Subtracting indices gives an offset
let k: Idx = j + offset; // Adding an offset to an index gives an index
// let _ = i + j; -- You can't add indices
```

I managed ([with some difficulty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004500/generically-implementing-a-trait-for-all-concrete-types-implementing-another-tra/71010565#71010565)) to implement `std::iter::Step` so I can also iterate through a range of indices

```rust
for k in i .. j { /* ... */ }
```

but now I've set my eyes on a higher goal: I also want to use ranges of these types to slice into sequences

```rust
let v: Vec<sometype> = vec![...];
let w: &[sometype] = &v[i..j]; // Slice with a range of Idx
```

This should be a simple matter of implementing `std::ops::Index` and `std::ops::IndexMut`, except that the type system won't let me implement

```rust
impl<I,T> std::ops::Index<std::ops::Range<I>> for Vec<T>
where I: /* my types */
{ ... }
```

for a wrapper type, or a generic

```rust
impl<I,T> std::ops::Index<std::ops::Range<Wrapper<I>>> for Vec<T>
where I: /* my types */
{ ... }
```

where `Wrapper` is the type I actually use and `I` a trait that helps me write generic code.

The problem is that both `Index` and `Range` are defined outside of my crate, so this kind of specialisation is not allowed. Or is it?

Is there any way that I can implement a trait for a generic type outside my crate when its generic parameters are from within my crate?

Or, better still, is there any way to tap into the syntactic sugar of the `..` operator, so I can get a wrapped type? What I *really* want is to wrap `Range` to get the same behaviour and then some. I can do that by wrapping `Range` and implementing `Deref`, but if I go that route, I lose the syntactic sugar of the `..` operator.

It is not a big problem, but I can imagine some confusion when you could write

```rust
for k in i .. j { /* ... */ }
```

like you can for the built-in types, but you have to use

```rust
let w: &[type] = &v[range(i,j)];
```

for slicing. It gets even more cumbersome if I want to allow slices such as `i..`, `..j` to be wrapped. (The `..` slice doesn't matter here, it won't get my types anyway). If I did that, I would need constructors for three types of ranges, or some ugly wrapping using `Option`, I think.

The `..` syntactic sugar is really neat, but from what I have explored you just cannot use that much for ranges of your own types. You can define ranges and you can, with some hacking, iterate through them, but you can't index with them.

Tell me I'm wrong, or let me know if there are any tricks that gets the job done, or even half-done. Or, if this is indeed impossible, let me know so I can stop wasting time on it and write a wrapper class and give up on the `..` operator.

**Update** I have put a simplified example in [playgrounds](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6231dba483d785a63fba51d8fe3895e4)

Comment: I think this should be possible. What error are you running into? Can you provide a more complete example? BTW "specialization" is the wrong word for what you're trying to do (just implement a trait with generics). Specialization is when you're providing a special implementation for a subset of an existing implementation.

Comment: On second thought, this may only be possible for concrete types. Have you considered using a macro to define the impls?

Comment: Your best bet here is to newtype `Vec`.

Comment: Is the issue that `Index` and `Range` are defined outside your crate, or that Rust provides no way for you to specify that your own types don't implement [`SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html) (since `Vec` already implements `Index<Range<impl SliceIndex>>`)? I think if you don't make `I` generic, and instead separately write the `impl` for each value of `I` you want, you should be ok.

Comment: @PitaJ It sort of is specialisation I want; I want Range<Sometype<T>> to behave differently than Range<T>, but I realise that I cannot do this in Rust. With that in mind, I am content to define other traits for Range<Sometype<T>> to give this special behaviour. I can't do that for indexing either, because I'm not allowed to implement Index<Range<SometypeA>> for Vec<SometimeB> when Index and Vec are not from my crate. I've made a simplified example here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6231dba483d785a63fba51d8fe3895e4

Comment: I can do it using macros for sure. That is how I implement the operators for the types, and how I implement single index access. I just think that once there are generics, I should be able to use them, rather than use macros as if I was back in C.

Comment: @BallpointBen The problem is exactly that once I wrap my local type in a Range<> generics, it is no longer a local type, and then I am not allowed to implement traits for it.

Comment: The reason this is not specialization is because `Range<Yourtype>` is not a subset of any existing implementation on `Range`.

Comment: If you don't want to implement a newtype of Vec, you could instead create an extension trait adding various convenience methods for your usage, like a custom `get(&self, range: Range<Yourtype>)`

Comment: @PitaJ Since `Range<T>` is implemented for *all* types `T` and I want special behaviour for *some* types `Idx<T>`, I don't get why it isn't a specialisation, but never mind. No point in arguing over terminology. Right now, I'm working on a solution with a wrapped `Range` (in some cases I want ranges as `enum`s instead of separate types anyway, so if I can't use raw `Range` that will probably be where I will go). I have an implementation for those, but still need to work out how to wrap the sequence type. It will probably end up being through macros.

Comment: The Range operator exists for all types T, yes. But that's not the impl you care about (and isn't really an impl at all), you really care about SliceIndex (or Index<Range<T>>) which is only implemented for Ranges of primitive types. So it's not specialization, because it wouldn't conflict which any existing impls. You problem is orphan rules, and specialization refers to a specific nightly feature in rust.

Comment: @PitaJ I wasn't aware that specialisation rules were part of nightly. And of course, you are right that it isn't specialisation in the sense that Range isn't a trait and I am not specialising it (as much as I would like to). I have most of a solution now with mostly trait programming and a few macros, but I keep running into problems, so I plan to look at ways to work with SliceIndex a little later when I have time for this project again. If macros are needed, then macros it is; I just prefer to keep macro-generated code to a minum as it is hell to debug.

Comment: Hmm, that was a short exploration of SliceIndex. It looks like they took great pains to prevent me from implementing those with my own types. So that is pretty useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

By definition of the [orphan rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules):

> Given `impl<P1..=Pn> Trait<T1..=Tn> for T0`, an `impl` is valid only if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - Trait is a [local trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#local-trait)
> - All of
>
>   - At least one of the types `T0..=Tn` must be a [local type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#local-type). Let `Ti` be the first such type.
>   - No [uncovered type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#uncovered-type) parameters `P1..=Pn` may appear in `T0..Ti` (excluding `Ti`)
>
> Only the appearance of *uncovered* type parameters is restricted. Note that for the purposes of coherence, [fundamental types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html#fundamental-type-constructors) are special. The T in Box is not considered covered, and Box is considered local.

> #### Local trait
>
> A `trait` which was defined in the current crate. A trait definition is local or not independent of applied type arguments. Given `trait Foo<T, U>`, `Foo` is always local, regardless of the types substituted for `T` and `U`.

> #### Local type
>
> A `struct`, `enum`, or `union` which was defined in the current crate. This is not affected by applied type arguments. `struct Foo` is considered local, but `Vec<Foo>` is not. `LocalType<ForeignType>` is local. Type aliases do not affect locality.

As neither `Index` nor `Range` nor `Vec` are local, and `Range` is not a fundamental type, you cannot `impl<T> Index<Range<...>> for Vec<T>`, no matter what you put in the place of the `...`.

The reason for these rules is that nothing prevents `Range` or `Vec` from implementing `impl<T, Idx> Index<Range<Idx>> for Vec<T>`. Such impl does not exist, and probably never will, but the rules are the same among all types, and in the general case this definitely can happen.

You cannot overload the range operator either - it always creates a `Range` (or `RangeInclusive`, `RangeFull`, etc.).

The only solution I can think about is to create a newtype wrapper for `Vec`, as suggested in the comments.

If you want your vector to return a wrapped slice, you can use a bit of unsafe code:

```rust
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut, Range, Deref, DerefMut};

#[repr(transparent)] // Because of this we can soundly cast `&{mut }[T]` to `&{mut }MySlice<T>`.
pub struct MySlice<T>([T]);

impl<'a, T> From<&'a [T]> for &'a MySlice<T> {
    fn from(v: &'a [T]) -> &'a MySlice<T> {
        unsafe { &*(v as *const [T] as *const MySlice<T>) }
    }
}
impl<'a, T> From<&'a mut [T]> for &'a mut MySlice<T> {
    fn from(v: &'a mut [T]) -> &'a mut MySlice<T> {
        unsafe { &mut *(v as *mut [T] as *mut MySlice<T>) }
    }
}

impl<T> Index<usize> for MySlice<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, idx: usize) -> &Self::Output { &self.0[idx] }
}
impl<T> IndexMut<usize> for MySlice<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, idx: usize) -> &mut Self::Output { &mut self.0[idx] }
}

impl<T> Index<Range<usize>> for MySlice<T> {
    type Output = MySlice<T>;
    fn index(&self, idx: Range<usize>) -> &Self::Output { self.0[idx].into() }
}
impl<T> IndexMut<Range<usize>> for MySlice<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, idx: Range<usize>) -> &mut Self::Output { (&mut self.0[idx]).into() }
}
// And so on, for all range types...

pub struct MyVec<T>(pub Vec<T>);

impl<T> Deref for MyVec<T> {
    type Target = MySlice<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { self.0.as_slice().into() }
}
impl<T> DerefMut for MyVec<T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target { self.0.as_mut_slice().into() }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not solve this by implementing my own sequences. I often need to take slices of sequences in divide-and-conquer recursions, so I want my types to work on slices. I suspect it will be quite cumbersome to have to wrap and unwrap slices everywhere in the code, to the point where this exercise will be useless. At least I would have to automatically wrap things, so if v: MyVec then w = &v[MyRange] would give me a wrapped MyWrapped([T]) somehow, and &w[MyRange] would give me another wrapped slice. I can give it a try...

Comment: No, maybe that idea is dead on arrival simply because the Index trait requires me to return a reference, so I can't wrap that... I'm slowly coming to the realisation that Rust is designed, purposely or accidentally, to prevent me defining new index types...

Comment: @ThomasMailund Quite wrong. Even rustc [defines its own index types for each type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_index/vec/index.html) to prevent mistakes. But it is indeed impossible to achieve the same amount of comfort. You can wrap the range type if you prefer. I'll edit the answer to show how you can wrap slices, though this require a bit of unsafe code.

Comment: My comment was (mostly) intended as a joke, and of course I can get there if I give up on some syntactic sugar. I just don't want to ;) Thanks a bunch for the link, I wasn't aware of indices there, and that looks like a perfect place to find inspiration. Also thanks for the updated answer; I can definitely use that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sort-of solution, involving a new `Range` in my own crate, and a lot of hacking. The full code is in [playgrounds](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0756a40b1bcfb34279493d059bf39622). It is a slow compile (lots of type inference, I guess), so you might have to download it to run it. Sorry about that.

There is a bunch of meta-programming to define new index types, but the gist of it is that I use a trait to specify different types and a wrapper to hold the underlying numbers.

```rust
// A dummy type to illustrate the types I want to work with
// Different TypeInfo will give me different and incompatible
// types that wrap integers, which is what I want.
trait TypeInfo {
    type WrappedType: num::PrimInt;
}

// A wrapper wraps the type from the TypeInfo trait;
// the TypeInfo trait specifies the type when I define what
// operations I will allow.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Wrapper<T: TypeInfo>(T::WrappedType);
```

Then I have another trait to specify if a given index is allowed to index in a given sequence type.

```rust
// Trait that determines which sequences an index can index
trait CanIndex<Seq: ?Sized> {}
```

although I am not sure if this is the right solution for that...

Anyway, for most of Rust's types, I need to use `usize` for indexing, so I have another trait that specifies if I have such a bugger.

```rust
// For indexing... (You get too deeply nested genetics without it)
// Maybe I can get rid of it, but that is for another day...
pub trait IndexType {
    fn as_index(&self) -> usize;
}
impl<TI> IndexType for Wrapper<TI>
where
    TI: TypeInfo<WrappedType = usize>,
{
    fn as_index(&self) -> usize {
        self.0
    }
}
```

While it doesn't make me happy to have to implement `Index` for every sequence type, at least every generic one, I don't think there is any way around that. For single indices, it is just this:

```rust
// Generic index implementation. (The real situation is a bit more
// complicated because I need to specify which types each index type
// is allowed to index, but this is the gist of it)

// Indexing a single element in a vector
impl<TI, T> std::ops::Index<Wrapper<TI>> for Vec<T>
where
    TI: TypeInfo,
    TI: CanIndex<Vec<T>>,
    Wrapper<TI>: IndexType,
{
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: Wrapper<TI>) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[i.as_index()]
    }
}

// Indexing a single element in a slice
impl<TI, T> std::ops::Index<Wrapper<TI>> for [T]
where
    TI: TypeInfo,
    TI: CanIndex<[T]>,
    Wrapper<TI>: IndexType,
{
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, i: Wrapper<TI>) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[i.as_index()]
    }
}
```

For my new `Range` type, I went with an `enum`. It will be more convenient for the things I want to do with it.

```rust
// My own type of ranges, now that I cannot use the built-in type...
/// Wrapper of Range that we can work with within Rust's type system
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Range<Idx> {
    Closed(Idx, Idx), // start..end
    Left(Idx),        // start..
    Right(Idx),       // ..end
    Full,             // ..
}
```

The type needs a constructor, which is complicated by Rust creating different types when you use the `..` operator, but you can do it like this:

```rust
pub trait GenRange<R, Idx> {
    fn range(r: R) -> Range<Idx>;
}
/*

 Now implement that trait for the different range types.
 Is there a better way?

 */

// Now I can build ranges with this function:
pub fn range<Idx, R: GenRange<R, Idx>>(r: R) -> Range<Idx> {
    R::range(r)
}
```

With this, I can also implement indexing for ranges. I can use `CanIndex<>` to specify that I can index with ranges for any type that I can index individual items with.

```rust
impl<Idx, T> std::ops::Index<Range<Idx>> for Vec<T>
where
    Idx: IndexType,
    Idx: CanIndex<Vec<T>>,
{
    type Output = [T];
    fn index(&self, r: Range<Idx>) -> &Self::Output {
        match r {
            Range::Closed(start, end) => &self[start.as_index()..end.as_index()],
            Range::Left(start) => &self[start.as_index()..],
            Range::Right(end) => &self[..end.as_index()],
            Range::Full => &self[..],
        }
    }
}

impl<Idx, T> std::ops::Index<Range<Idx>> for [T]
where
    Idx: IndexType,
    Idx: CanIndex<[T]>,
{
    type Output = [T];
    fn index(&self, r: Range<Idx>) -> &Self::Output {
        match r {
            Range::Closed(start, end) => &self[start.as_index()..end.as_index()],
            Range::Left(start) => &self[start.as_index()..],
            Range::Right(end) => &self[..end.as_index()],
            Range::Full => &self[..],
        }
    }
}
```

It got rather complicated, so I need to clean it up as much as I can, but at least I am beginning to believe that it can be done. And once that is done, I need to figure out a good way to add the usual `std::ops::Range` interface to `Range`. But this will do for today.